# Continuous function, based on conditions

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

$f(x)$ is a continuous function over all real values of x, and $f(f(0)) = 0$.

How can I prove that based on those conditions, the following statement is true: $$\exists a\in \mathbb{R}: f(a)=a$$

Comment: I suggest:  look at three cases, $f(0)=0, f(0)>0, f(0)<0$.  Considering the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$ might also help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(x) - x$ as lulu suggested.

Since $f(f(0)) = 0$, we have that $g(f(0)) = f(f(0)) - f(0) = 0 - f(0) = -f(0)$ and $g(0) = f(0) - 0 = f(0)$.

By applying the intermediate value theorem to $g(x)$ (which is continuous by assumption), there exists at least one $a$ in the interval $[f(0),0]$ (or in $[f(0),0]$ depending on the sign of $f(0)$) such that $g(a) = 0$ which is equivalent to $f(a) = a$.